# Where is the reporting server web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

On SSRS 2005 you can find a web service on `http://yourserver/reportservice/reportservice.asmx` which you can use to deploy your reports.

Is there a similar service on SSRS 2008 R2? Where? In case that this service doesn't exist, how can I deploy the reports by code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx

> If the report server is configured for
>   native mode or SharePoint integrate
>   mode, the WSDL for the management
>   endpoint can be accessed using one of
>   the following URL:
>
> http://_Server_Name_/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Check Reporting Services Configuration Manager under Start > SQL Server 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools to see if/where the web service is installed.

Comment: The report server configuration manager is installed on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn and is intalled since I can publish reports using business intelligence development studio. What I want is a way to deploy them using a C# application.

Comment: If you connect to your database server using the above tool it should list the Web Service URL

Comment: Hum.. I think we're mixing concepts were =/ Report Services Configuration Manager created a virtual directory in http://servername/reportservice. If I'll go there with a browser a can see to folders (Data Sources and Reports). Want a want is a web service that exists on SSRS 2005 in http://yourserver/reportservice/reportservice.asmx which I can reference on a Visual Studio project and use exposed methods.

Comment: Ah I see. In SQL Server 2008 / R2 it's been renamed to ReportService2010.asmx.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx